# downsample big numpy.ndarray on if condition in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large numpy.ndarray and I need to downsample this array based on the value of one column. My solution works, but is very slow

```
data_table = data_table[[i for i in range(0, len(data_table)) if data_table[i][7] > 0.2 and data_table[i][7] < 0.75]]
```

does anybody know what the fastest way is to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`column-slicing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) to select relevant columns and compare those against the thresholds in a vectorized manner to give us a mask of valid rows and then index into the rows for the rows filtered output -

```
out = data_table[(data_table[:,7] > 0.2) & (data_table[:,7] < 0.75)]
```